# How can I add a space to a string after every specified length of chars and pad the remaining characters with one space?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a coding challenge to encrypt a string and return the encrypted string with spaces after a specified length of characters. Also, the remaining characters left should be padded with additional space so that it will be up to the specified length of chars.
This is what I tried doing:

```js
const str =
  "If man was meant to stay on the ground, god would have given us roots.";

class SquareCode {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  // Remove spaces and punctuation
  normalizeString() {
    return this.text.replace(/[^\w]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
  }

  // Get number of columns
  size() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(this.normalizeString().length));
  }

  // Split string into chunks
  chunks() {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`.{1,${this.size()}}`, "g");
    return this.normalizeString().match(pattern);
  }

  // Encrypt String
  encryptString() {
    let code = "";
    const chunks = this.chunks();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.size(); ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < chunks.length; ++j) {
      code += chunks[j].slice(i, i + 1);

      const rowLength = this.size()-1;
      if (code.replace(/\s/g, '').length % rowLength === 0) code += ' ';
    }
  }
    return code;
  }
}

const work = new SquareCode(str);
console.log(work.encryptString());
```

This is the output I got: "imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghns seoau"

and this is the expected output: "imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau "

This is the link to the challenge to provide a better context
[Challenge](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_vCmCdtzIKGTIHyWBCRUpAcy86ZROg2u)

Comment: Why is that the expected output ?  It looks like you are adding a space after every 7th character up to the last segment because it ends there. "aohghn" is six characters.  It looks like what you got is almost correct except there is no space after the last "word".

Comment: Probably a better way, but if you move const rowLength = this.size()-1; after let code, and add if (code.replace(/\s/g, '').length % rowLength != 0) code += ' '; before return code it will at least give you a trailing space if you need one because the last "word" is not the right size.

Comment: It's not just the space in the last word. If you notice the second to the last word and the last word of the expected output is different from mine

Comment: "*with spaces after a specified length of characters*" - and how are they specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
const str =
  "If man was meant to stay on the ground, god would have given us roots.";

class SquareCode {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  // Remove spaces and punctuation
  normalizeString() {
    return this.text.replace(/[^\w]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
  }

  // Get number of columns
  size() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(this.normalizeString().length));
  }

  // Split string into chunks
  chunks() {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`.{1,${this.size()}}`, "g");
    return this.normalizeString().match(pattern);
  }

  // Encrypt String
  encryptString() {
    let code = "";
    const chunks = this.chunks();
    const size = this.size();
    console.log(chunks);
    for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < chunks.length; ++j) {
      code += chunks[j].slice(i, i + 1);
    }
    code += ' '
  }
    return code;
  }
}

const work = new SquareCode(str);

console.log(work.encryptString());
```

Slice returns an empty string when the chunk length is less than size, and a space is added after every "word" in code.  Although in the example in the instructions it looks like there are 2 spaces after "aohghn" and not just one, but in your question you have just one for the desired output:

"imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau "

vs.

"imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn(2 spaces)sseoau "